# need a better implementation of this FNV hashing alogithm in java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, hash

I have this, i would like to make it more efficient and if you need the whole hashset data structure i have created i can add it but im overall looking for something like this that takes any number of strings and stores them in my custom implementation of a hashset:

```
    private int hash(String key)
{
    int prime = 31;
    int hash = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        hash *= prime;
        hash ^= key.charAt(i);
    }

    if (hash < 0)
        hash *= -1;

    return hash % array.length;
}
```

Comment: If you want to generate hash code for an array of string well we have built in function like `Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`: `Arrays.hashCode(strArray)`. Simple and efficient

Comment: Sorry i didnt say, no use of the java api, i have to add word by word

Comment: Could please make it a little bit more clear. You are passing a String to hash function but the returning statement has `array.length`: where did this array come from ?

Comment: its the hashset array, it has a set amount, think of that as a number

Comment: Heres the Answer:                                                                                                                                                                                                           public int FNV(String word){ 
  int hash=0;
  for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
   hash *= 31;
   hash ^=+word.charAt(i);
  }
  if(hash<0){
   hash *=-1;
  }
  int endResult = hash % HashTable.length;
  return endResult;
 }

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

- It's generally accepted these days that 33 is a better choice of prime than 31, because it leads to fewer collisions in most non-English languages (English has about the same small number of collisions either way).
- Converting your string to a character array and accessing the elements that way rather than calling charAt() multiple times is likely to be faster
- The following code is inefficient:

  ```
  if (hash < 0)
       hash *= -1;
  ```

  This code is better, because (1) it doesn't use a processor multiply instruction, which is resource intensive, and (2) it doesn't produce branch mispredictions periodically:

  ```
  hash &= ~0x80000000;
  ```

Comment: Bullet point #1 above (prime 31 vs 33) is fascinating!  Do you have any sources that I can read to learn more?